# Debugging a custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I am an embedded C programmer (not a C++ one) trying to learn on my own how to create better simple GUIs for production. I've Googled this and can't find an answer, but may just be wording my search incorrectly.

I've created a custom widget and when I access it from Qt creator while debugging my application, the debugger does indeed step into the source code for the widget.

However, once in the source code for the widget, it jumps around wildly, starting at the first line of code, then jumping upwards into the lines of local variables when I hit F10 and eventually going down again into the code as I continue to hit F10. Sometimes some of the variables display `<Optimised out>` rather than the value they actually hold.

I have tried to make a debug install for the widget, but this makes no difference at all.

Is it actually possible to debug widgets like this? I've been going round and round in circles for hours on this and need to come up with a better way of getting to the bottom of why the program is crashing in a certain part of the custom widget.

Comment: Yes it is possible to debug a custom widget. It is no different than any other code. Would it be possible for you to provide an example of the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: sounds like you're trying to debug a release executable. Are you sure you have the proper configuration set?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, no I am not sure at all. My application is in debug mode for sure. The widget I recompiled as I originally described above but seems to have been edited out for some reason by doing "make debug install", but this didn't help. If you can describe exactly how to achieve this I'd be most grateful.

Comment: @J.Dunlop, I am not sure how to describe it other than above really. When I set a breakpoint in the app and step into the widget's code, hitting F11, then when I step through with F10 or F11, sometimes the arrow that shows the line you're on goes backwards and sometimes forward. Often, the values in the debugger show <Optimised out> rather than  their actual values. It all seems random! Maybe that's not really the question you're asking, apologies if so.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. I had a moment of clarity this morning when I went back to it. I'd completely forgotten about having to reference the library in the .pro file. So, even though I had copied the debug library to:

```
/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/designer/libcutescreenwidgetplugin.so
```

The problem was that the project file had:

```
LIBS += pathtosoucecode/build-CuteScreenWidgetPlugin-Desktop_9516b5-Release/libcutescreenwidgetplugin.so
```

Once I changed that reference to the debug library all the debugging information and single-step works perfectly.

It has now occurred to me that maybe I should really have:

```
LIBS += /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/designer/libcutescreenwidgetplugin.so
```

In my project file, so that once the debug version is installed it will automatically use that instead. It's maybe just one of those things that you get wrong when you have myraid things to learn with such a complicated system as Qt.